# How to automatically change the number of slides-to-show in angular-slick by window's width

Tags: angularjs

I'm a novice for angular. I want to make a slide show by using [angular-slick](http://vasyabigi.github.io/angular-slick/) and I want it to support a responsive website. Here is my example code,

```
<slick infinite="true" slides-to-show="4" slides-to-scroll="1" prev-arrow=".slick-prev" next-arrow=".slick-next">

        <div class="item">
            aaaa
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            bbbb
        </div>  
        <div class="item">
            cccc
        </div>  
        <div class="item">
            eeee
        </div>      
        <div class="item">
            ffff
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            gggg
        </div>                                                                  

    <a type="button" class="slick-prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"></i></a>
    <a type="button" class="slick-next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></i></a>
</slick>
```

According to the code, I set a slides-to-show = 4 but how to change it to 3 when the window size is less than 768px.

Really thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually ignore that, you can much more easily, set the attribute, based on a scope variable.

For example:

```
<slick ng-controller="<the controller's name>" infinite="true" slides-to-show="{{numberOfTiles}}" slides-to-scroll="1" prev-arrow=".slick-prev" next-arrow=".slick-next">
    </slick>


angular.module('<your module's name here>')
        .controller('<the controller's name>', ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window)
        {
            $scope.numberOfTiles = $window.width > 768? 4 : 3;
        }]);
```

<s>You have many options to accomplish that. One is to create a new directive, another is to attach a controller to the  element, which adjusts scope variables according to the window's size.</s>

The easiest way though, is to use ng-hide and ng-show.

```
<slick ng-show="screenIsWide" infinite="true" slides-to-show="3" slides-to-scroll="1" prev-arrow=".slick-prev" next-arrow=".slick-next">
</slick>
<slick ng-hide="screenIsWide" infinite="true" slides-to-show="4" slides-to-scroll="1" prev-arrow=".slick-prev" next-arrow=".slick-next">
</slick>
```

Have your `<slick .... > ... </slick>` inside an `ng-controller`, so that you have a local scope. In that local scope, have a variable `screenIsWide`, and through your controller, set it to true or false, according to the screen size.

For example:

```
angular.module('<your module's name here>')
    .controller('<the controller's name>', ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window)
    {
        $scope.screenIsWide = $window.width > 768;
    }]);
```

You can also change it according to resizes, through the controller (by listening to events like:  `$window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() { /*do stuff*/ });`

Comment: this doesnot autodetect the screen resize, you have to refresh the page everytime

Comment: My answer, calculates the window's size once, upon the controller's instantiation. I said: "You can also change it according to resizes, through the controller (by listening to events like: $window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() { /*do stuff*/ });"